# Theorem proof: difficulties with one argument

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

In this [pdf](http://math.ucsd.edu/~lni/math140/Supplementary.pdf), theorem $2.2$ (page $6$ or $103$- since it's not really the whole book) there is a point that I don't really understand fully.

$|a_n| < |l| + 1$ for all $n \ge N$, and then the next argument says $|a_n| \le \max(a_1, a_2, ... a_N, |l| + 1)$, and thus concluded there.

Could someone explain what I'm missing in understanding this argument?

Why does it hold?

Comment: Do you understand everything in the reasoning until the very end?

Comment: yes! i do understand up to that point.

Comment: The proof ends with $(\forall n\in \Bbb N)(|a_n|\leq M)$, where $M=\max \left(\{a_1, \ldots, a_N, |l|+1\}\right)$.

Now what does it mean to say a sequence is bounded?

Comment: yes it does. but why is the inequality true?

Comment: oh, i'm new in the site. i didnt know how to do that...

Comment: In the future try to format your questions using $\LaTeX$. Some tips on how to use it can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as you can see from the second line in the proof, there exists $N\in \Bbb N$ such that $(\forall n\in \Bbb N)(n\ge N\Longrightarrow |a_n-l|<1)$. This implies that for all $n\in \Bbb N$ such that $n\ge N$ you'll have $a_n<l+1$ (just play around with absolute value to see this, it's easy).

But what happens for $n<N$? You don't know, but what you do know is that for any $n<N$ you'll have $a_n\leq\max \left(\{a_1, \ldots, a_N\}\right)$.

Can you conclude the final inequality from the two paragraphs above?

Comment: Oh! I think I know now why it holds!!

Comment: eh, fail of using LaTex up there... anyways, I do understand. Thank you!
edit: I removed the comment I had written before

Comment: @user65165 No problem. Do note that I only proved that $a_n$ is bounded above (notice the lack of $| \space \cdot \space |$). The bound from below follows from the inequality $|a_n-l|<1$ is a similar manner.

Comment: I think the reasoning could be the following... since for all abs(a_n) we know it is less or equal than abs(l) + 1, then the abs(a_n) is also less or equal than the max of the set containing terms from 1 to N and abs(l) + 1. This is a true because if the terms from 1 to N are less than a_n then it doesn't matter because we already have [abs(l) + 1] in the set and thus it'll give us a true inequality. In any case the inequality is true. But, now this inequality in fact tells us that abs(n) is less or equal to sth, thus it is bounded. Is this correct?

Comment: @user65165 At the beginning you say that for all $n$ you have $|a_n|\leq |l|+1$. Is this really what you mean? Because if that's true, then the conlusion follows imediately because $|l|+1\leq M$.

Comment: @user65165 Anyway, a possible way is from $|a_n-l|<1$, infer that $-1+l<a_n$, then by taking the absolute value and using the triangular inequality you get $|a_n|<|-l+1|\leq |l|+1$ and then it's similar to the case I wrote out.

Comment: I meant for all n > or equal to N.

Comment: @user65165 Seems correct.